# Issue with py4vasp and Jupyter Lab Integration on Windows 10?

Tags: vasp, python, density-of-states, windows-operating-system

I am currently working on a project involving py4vasp for crystal structure analysis. I have successfully installed py4vasp, Jupyter Lab, and Jupyter Notebook in a Conda environment. When I attempt to use py4vasp within a Jupyter Lab notebook by importing

```
from py4vasp import Calculation
```

I encounter an issue where it gets stuck on "loading widget."

Environment Details:

1. Operating System: Windows 10
2. Conda Environment: Anaconda Powershell Prompt (Miniconda 3)

I have verified that all the necessary Jupyter widgets are installed in my Conda environment using `conda list`, so it seems like there might be a specific compatibility or configuration issue.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem with py4vasp and Jupyter Lab integration on Windows 10 or in a similar Conda environment? If so, could you please share any insights or solutions you might have? Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot of the error, so that people understand what you mean by ```"I encounter an issue where it gets stuck on loading widget."``` ?